# Cannot access an attribute value using read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv, svm

The label object in the following code cannot be found. I faced this problem before and the solution was to remove sep and header parameters from read.csv. Although i have removed them i still have the same error which is:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'label' not found
```

code:

```
library(e1071)
dataset <- read.csv("C:/Users/Backup/Desktop/pos.csv")
# Subset the dataset dataset to only 2 labels and 2 features
dataset.part = subset(dataset, label != 1)
dataset.part$label = factor(dataset.part$label)
dataset.part = dataset.part[, c(1,2,5)]

# Fit svm model
fit = svm(label ~ ., data=dataset.part, type='C-classification',     kernel='linear')
```

when i run this names(dataset) i got:

```
[1] "X"     "V1"    "V2"    "V3"    "V4"    "V5"    "V6"    "V7"    "V8"    "V9"   
[11] "V10"   "V11"   "V12"   "V13"   "V14"   "V15"   "V16"   "V17"   "V18"   "V19"  
[21] "V20"   "label"
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: dput(dataset) please?

Comment: .Names = c("X", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", 
"V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12867L)) a huge amount of data appeared but these are the last rows.

Comment: Add it to your question. The "huge amount of data" is important to help you.

Comment: You removed the 'label' column when you only took the 1,2,5 columns.